# Downloading in background. Nativescript-Angular

Tags: javascript, android, angular, typescript, nativescript

I have already asked similar question, but, as I understood, it was too complicated. So, I made a simple version. I am developing a multi-platform app using NativeScript and Angular and have to download a large amount of data from the server and continue doing it in the background even when the user hides my app (sample: when you install a app from Play Market, you can switch to another app and loading continues). How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe this article in official documentation will help you https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/ios-runtime/how-to/backgroundexecution

Comment: Yes, I have seen it, but this method works only on iOS and I would like to use something suitable for both platforms